# YouTube integration like Facebook feature?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown

Could we have better integration with YouTube so that video links can show on-site, streaming from YouTube, like Facebook statuses with automatic HTML insertion?
I asked [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35258/what-do-jews-think-angels-look-like) and think that feature would be so cool.

Comment: That question in particular would not be a good place to use such a feature. After all, the video is completely unnecessary to the question, just an aside, since your question is what angels look like, irrespective of what's in the video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is supported by the platform, but we'd need a bit more evidence that this feature would actually be useful, not detrimental to the site. We want to allow for videos where they make sense in answers, such as a frequent need to demonstrate how to do something.

We don't normally enable it unless it's clearly needed because people tend to say "Oh look, neat, I can embed a video, so I guess I should go find one" (that actually happens more often than you'd think).

I don't, at this time, see a really resounding need to enable it here. If that changes, then we just need at least a dozen or so specific links where having inline video would have made a good difference in the coherency of an answer.